# Should workplace pay you for time taken to read employee handbook?

Tags: salary, contracts, company-policy, canada

Especially during the on boarding process there is a lot of paper work to fill out. At some companies I worked for this is done during the work day and is paid for. Other companies just send all the paper work to my home where I do it on my own time and not get paid. Is one style more common over the other? Is it even legal to not pay for the time taken to read a 50+ page employee handbook? If a handbook can be "updated from time to time" is it really expected to know it well?

This second part may be a separate question but it gives context to the first: I recently was told I had violated a policy that was in the handbook. The handbook was 50 pages and I was not paid to read, let alone memorize, each part of it. That being said, **I did read it** but not closely scrutinize. (It turned out the policy wasn't legal anyway)

Comment: The One style more common than other would be quite opinion-based IMHO, the other questions can be answered I think

Comment: What if you took that handbook to work and read it during work hours?

Comment: @DarkCygnus in some jobs this isn't possible. For example customer facing roles where all the time you're with a customer.

Comment: Employment regulations vary greatly across Canada - I learned this the hard way when I moved from Saskatchewan to Alberta. Could you please provide what province you're in?

Comment: @fetcheatable posted an answer for you to consider

Comment: In the example given the employer is in Ontario so Ontario law applies. However, I work out of BC and many local employers do this in my experience.

Comment: In that case, please indicate your province so we can try to give better answers

Comment: The handbook is mostly there to A) answer common questions employees have, and B) have policies/warnings in writing so if they want to ding/hang you for something they can say, "well, its written in the handbook, and you signed here that you read it and agreed to it...". And if you work in a low-level position or for a large company (mostly any company large enough to have a sizable handbook), it is almost certainly B. But you should read it well regardless of if they provide time on the clock to read it, because sometimes it says you have rights/privileges you didn't know you had. :)

Comment: I've always done this as part of the HR/Dept induction processes

Answer (score 6):

Checking [FedDev Ontario Small Business Services](http://www.cbo-eco.ca/en/index.cfm/managing/employees/employment-regulations-hiring/) led me to [this other page on employment standards](https://www.ontario.ca/document/your-guide-employment-standards-act-0/hours-work). On it, on the Training Time section we can read (emphasis mine):

> ## Training time
>
> **Time spent by an employee in training that is required by the employer or by law is counted as work time**. For example, where the training is required because the employee is a **new employee** or where it is required as a condition of continued employment in a position, the training time is considered to be work time.
>
> Time spent in training that is not required by the employer or by law in order for an employee to do his or her job is not counted as work time. For example, where an employee hoping for a promotion with the employer takes training in order to qualify for it, time spent taking the training is not considered to be work time.

I am not a lawyer, nor do I live in Canada, Ontario, but this seems quite clear to me that any training (reading the Handbook is training) is considered work time.

So (again, IANAL), it would seem to me that:

1. You can read it at home, after work, and it *should* be considered overtime, or...
2. You read it at work, which is normal work time.

Comment: Interesting. I've had quite a few jobs where the expectation was to watch a few e.g. anti-harassment videos from home before starting.This time wasn't paid for.

Comment: @fetcheatable do note that this seems to apply to Ontario. If you work there, then yes, but if you live elsewhere things could be a bit different. Now regarding that what you say, if you haven't started the job yet... then well I think it could be some sort of loophole as you are technically not working (yet), so watching the video is not (yet) training? I don't know for sure...

Comment: @fetcheatable some 'training' things can "Get complex..." with their legal requirements. _Legally_ to continue your employment you're required to not harass your coworkers, and your employer, _legally_, may be required to provide you with anti-harassment training materials. However, whether you actually read/watch them, and whether or not that has to be done on company time, can be in more of a grey area of the law. - Reading? Not strictly legally required. Not harassing Coworkers? Strictly legally required.